# Non-monotonic evolution of runtime with increasing parallelization

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm running some runtime tests to understand what I can gain from parallelization and how it affects runtime (linearly?).
For a given integer `n` I successively compute the `n`-th Fibonacci number and vary the degree of parallelization by allowing to compute each Fibonacci number `i` in `{0,1,...,n}` by using up to 16 parallel processes.

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import multiprocessing as mp


# n-te Fibonacci Zahl
def f(n: int):
    if n in {0, 1}:
        return n
    return f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) 


if __name__ == "__main__":
    K = range(1, 16 + 1)
    n = 100
    N = range(n)
    
    df_dauern = pd.DataFrame(index=K, columns=N)
    
    for _n in N: 
        _N = range(_n)
        print(f'\nn = {_n}')
        for k in K:
            
                    
            start = time.time()
            
            pool = mp.Pool(k)
            pool.map(f, _N)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()
            
            ende = time.time()
            dauer = ende - start    
            m, s = divmod(dauer, 60)
            h, m = divmod(m, 60)
            h, m, s = round(h), round(m), round(s)
            
            df_dauern.loc[k, _n] = f'{h}:{m}:{s}'
            
            print(f'... k = {k:02d}, Dauer: {h}:{m}:{s}')
    
    df_dauern.to_excel('Dauern.xlsx')
```

In the following DataFrame I display the duration (h:m:s) for `n` in `{45, 46, 47}`.

```
        45       46       47
1   0:9:40  0:15:24  0:24:54
2   0:7:24  0:13:23  0:22:59
3    0:5:3   0:9:37   0:19:7
4   0:7:18   0:7:19  0:15:29
5   0:7:21   0:7:17  0:15:35
6   0:3:41   0:9:34   0:9:36
7   0:3:40   0:9:46   0:9:34
8   0:3:41   0:9:33   0:9:33
9   0:3:39   0:9:33   0:9:33
10  0:3:39   0:9:32   0:9:32
11  0:3:39   0:9:34   0:9:45
12  0:3:40    0:6:4   0:9:37
13  0:3:39   0:5:54   0:9:32
14  0:3:39   0:5:55   0:9:32
15  0:3:40   0:5:53   0:9:33
16  0:3:39   0:5:55   0:9:33
```

In my opinion the results are odd in two dimensions. First, the duration is not monotonically decreasing for increasing parallelization and second, runtime is not linearly decreasing (that is, double processes, half runtime).

- Is this behavior to be expected?
- Is this behavior due to the chosen example of computing Fibonacci numbers?
- How is it even possible that runtime increases with increasing parallelization (e.g. always when moving from 2 to 3 parallel processes)?
- How come it does not make a difference whether I use 6 or 16 parallel processes?

Comment: what is your cpu and ram sticks count/clock ?

Comment: 2,3 GHz and 768 GB if that is what you are asking for. What's count/clock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because of multiprocessing scheduling algorithm and the fact that the task has factorial complexity, by default the pool will choose a chunksize that is relative to the number of workers

basically multiprocessing splits work into equal chunks to reduce serialization overhead, the chunksize is given by.

```py
chunksize, extra = divmod(len(iterable), len(self._pool) * 4)
chunksize += bool(extra)
```

for 4 and 5 workers, the chunk size is the same (3), and 99.9% of the time is taken by the last 3 tasks, which are scheduled in the same core (because they are in 1 chunk), so 1 core ends up doing 99.9% of the work regardless of the core count, the extra 3 seconds are most likely scheduling overhead (more workers = more scheduling), you'll get a speedup if you set the `chunksize=1` in `pool.map` parameters manually, as each of these 3 tasks will be scheduled to a different core.

for worker number higher than 6, the chunksize is calculated to be 2, but you have an odd number of tasks, which means you will always wait for the last task that is scheduled, which is the longest one, the entire `3:40` minutes are in a single function, it cannot be broken down further, so it doesn't matter if you launch 6 workers or a 100, you are still limited by the slowest task (or actually the slowest chunk).

Comment: Ah, thanks. So runtime equals calculation of `f(n)` for all `k`, as calculating `f(n)` has the highest complexity. If all tasks where equally complex, then doubling processes/cores would half runtime.

Comment: @clueless this is only true up to a certain limit that depends on your cpu and Ram speed, but depending on what you are running the first few processes will have an almost linear improvement in throughput, until you start hitting one of those bottlenecks.